# How do I scrape status code from the log file? (in c++)

Tags: c++

Each of the string in log file looks like this:

44.225.84.206 - - [12/Mar/2020:07:02:43 +0530] "GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 73 "-" "AWS Security Scanner"

I have to count the no of status code(here 200) in the file.

Comment: what blocks you to do that ? where is exactly your problem ? you just have to read file content line per line and count how much time there is the expected pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions through the `std::regex` library. `"\".+\" (\\d+)"` pattern matches any digit after any quoted string and a space. Since your status code is immediately after a quoted string `"GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200`, it will match the first numeric characters till space, so 73 won't be matched. Note that if your log file contains quoted strings anywhere else followed by a space and digits, it will match that too, modify the pattern if needed.

`std::regex_search()` will match the line and store the result in `match`. `match.str(1)` will return the first group; the contents of the first `()` i.e. 200 as a string. Convert it to an `int` if needed.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream log_file("statlog.txt");
    std::regex re("\".+\" (\\d+)");
    std::smatch match;
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> status_code;
    while(std::getline(log_file, line)) {

        if(std::regex_search(line.cbegin(), line.cend(),match, re))
        status_code.push_back(match.str(1));
    }
    for(auto& elem : status_code) std::cout  << elem << '\n';
}
```

This stores all status codes in a vector of strings.

And this is, of course, if you are using C++11 or higher.